# ConnectionString error appears whilst running the setup for a VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net, installation

When I run the installation for my application created in VB.net, I get a message: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. Please note that I am installing the software, not running it. I therefore cannot understand why it is looking at the connection string at this stage.

- It is a clean installation, i.e. the application is not present on the computer.
- SQL Server Express (2018) has been installed on the computer.
- The application was developed in the latest version of Visual Studio Express

Comment: Exactly what information do you get and in what form?  That error message indicates that an exception has been thrown somewhere.  Can you access the stack trace for that exception to determine exactly where?

Comment: By the way, the latest version of an Express edition of VS is 2010.  Do you actuallymean VS Community 2017?  The Community edition, which is much more fully-featured than Express, took over as the free edition in 2012 or 2013 (can't recall which now).

Comment: @jmcilhinney There is only a messagebox that appears at the end of the installation with the title 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized' and the message 'Error'. Nothing else :(  The software runs perfectly on the development machine.